# After installing VS 2010 - Generic Host Process For Win32 Services problem starts

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, sp3, visual-studio-2010

After installing VS 2010 trial I am getting this error "Generic Host Process For Win32 Services Encountered A Problem and needs to close.

When this message pops my computer just stuck and I can not even restart it normally. I have found one fix on net but after that fix I can not access my LAN.

This fix change these values in registry.

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\netbt\parameters TransportBindName
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\OLE EnableDCOM
```

If I revert these registry changes then I again start getting 'Generic Host Process For Win32 Services'

I have uninstall VS 2010 but this problem persist. This problem is not because of any virus.

**Edit:**
When ever I install Windows Xp Service Pack 3. This problem starts

Any help to fix this or I have to re install Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Server Package? Did you mean Service Pack?

Comment: @Hello71:- Yes & edited.